# Config timestamps Rails (Solutions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, config

as I can set the timestamps of rails to take the time to bogota?
Can I set the timestamps of Rails to take the time of Bogota?

I added these lines only

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Answer (score 0):

The string you are searching for is: "America/Bogota"

```
config.time_zone = "America/Bogota"
```

For more details take a look at [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html)

Comment: Did you restart your server?